# Codeigniter wrecking Ajax output?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is driving me batty...

I am using the CodeIgniter framework and in it I have my nice php-side of the AJAX function working (& being called) perfectly:

```
function save_new_schedule_set() {
    //do stuff...
    echo json_encode($arrResult);
}
```

which, when I use step-through debugging, I can see IS producing the correct result, i.e:

```
{"id":128}
```

However, somehow when this happy result is being received back by the calling (jquery) function:

```
function SaveSchedule() {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){ alert('Working'); },
        error: function(o,c,m) { 
            alert(m + " : " + o + " : " + c); 
        }
    });
    var $url = getPHPinit_AddEvent("base_url") + getLink_AddEvent("save_schedule");
    $.post($url, {
        "description"   : $description,
        "start_time"    : $startTime,
        "end_time"      : $endTime
    }, "json"); 
}
```

it always triggers error() rather than success(), Specifically:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character : [object Object] : parsererror
```

Upon inspection w/firebug, error().o.responseText does contain the expected result...

```
{"id":128}
```

...but it's **prepended** with a whole lot of ActiveRecord  junk that looks like it was put there by CodeIgnitor:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid rgb(153, 0, 0); padding-left: 20px; margin: 0px 0px 10px;">
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given</p>
<p>Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1109</p>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid rgb(153, 0, 0); padding-left: 20px; margin: 0px 0px     10px;">
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given</p>
<p>Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1110</p>
...
</div>{"id":128}
```

And obviously all that extra junk will blow up the parser.

Has anyone run into this problem before? Any ideas how I can get out of it?

Thank-you!!!

PS: This is especially mysterious because the calling page has other AJAX calls that are working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Doh! Issue is being triggered by non-fatal warnings issued from code in my model class on the php side. Codeignitor is trying to process these warnings to the screen, which is prepending them to the AJAX output, thereby bolluxing it for the json parser.

Comment: D'oh! I run into this all the time on the site I'm working on. We ended up adding a flag (`debuginfo=on`) so that we can turn the errors on/off. Then you can pull up the request alone in a separate tab and look at the errors. Good find!

Comment: Wouldn't it be cool if the codeigniter gods added some kind of function flag (like fname = [fname]_ajax) that made its built-in error handling for that function more AJAX compatible? Like by automatically returning it in the json_encode() output instead of pushing it to the screen? Got equivalent functionality? Please post here!!!

Comment: [This post has some info on how to suppress errors/warnings and other suggestions that might be useful.](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/125687/)